# using onShow and onLoad for dijit.layout.ContentPane created programatic

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a ContentPane created both declarative and programmatic.

Declarative :

```
<div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" id="abccp" href="abc.php?id=1" title="abc" onShow="do_abc()">
```

Programmatic

```
var obj_abc;
var abchref= "abc.php?id=1";
obj_abc = new dijit.layout.ContentPane({id:'abccp',title:'abc', href:abchref});
```

How can I call do_abc() in the programmatic ex

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To be technically equivalent to your first example, you'd just include `onShow: do_abc` within the arguments object passed to ContentPane's constructor.  (Note no parentheses after `do_abc` - we're interested in the function object itself, not the result of calling it!)

However, if you'd like to do it in a bit more extensible of a fashion, then I'd suggest doing it like this:

```
obj_abc = new dijit.layout.ContentPane(...);
obj_abc.connect(obj_abc, 'onShow', do_abc);
```

What this does is perform a hookup such that whenever `obj_abc`'s `onShow` method is called, the `do_abc` function will in turn be called (though in the context of `obj_abc`, which presumably is what you want anyway).  You also get the following added bonuses:

- It no longer clobbers any default functionality that might be originally present in the method (though in this case, `onShow` is a stub meant to be clobber-able)
- You can connect any number of functions to `onShow` in this way
- The connection will automatically be torn down when the widget is destroyed (as opposed to `dojo.connect` which you would have to tear down manually).

For more information:

- http://dojotoolkit.org/api/dijit/_Widget/connect

Comment: Hi Ken I have problems with some dojo can you please check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122473/dojo-is-not-working