# Dojo is not working

Tags: dojo, dijit.layout

I am new at dojo and here is my code:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.1/dojo/resources/dojo.css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.1/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../../../resources/themes/default/styles/layout.css" th:href="@{/resources/default/styles/layout.css}"></link>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.1/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="parseOnLoad:true"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../../resources/dev/scripts/Spring.js" th:src="@{/resources/spring/Spring.js}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../../resources/dev/scripts/Spring-Dojo.js" th:src="@{/resources/spring/Spring-Dojo.js}"></script>


 <div id="gridContainer" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        dojo.require('dojo.store.JsonRest');
        dojo.require('dijit.layout.ContentPane');
        dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
        dojo.require('dojox.grid.DataGrid');
        dojo.require('dojo.data.ObjectStore');
        dojo.require('dijit.form.TextBox');
        dojo.require('dojox.data.AndOrReadStore');
        dojo.require('dojo._base.xhr');
        dojo.require('dojo.json')
        dojo.require('dojo.domReady');

        dojo.ready(function() {

            var appLayout = new dijit.layout.ContentPane({
                            id: "appLayout"
                            }, "appLayout");

            var textBox = new dijit.form.TextBox({
                        name: "searchbox",
                        placeHolder: "Search ..."
                        });

            textBox.placeAt('appLayout');              
            appLayout.placeAt('gridContainer');

            appLayout.startup();     
        });
    </script>
```

firefox tells me that there is an error:

```
TypeError: d is null
(undefined="[object Object]", undefined="null")ContentPane.js (línea 4)
(undefined="[object Object]", undefined=""appLayout"")_WidgetBase.js (línea 4)
(undefined="[object Object]", undefined=""appLayout"")dojo.js (línea 104)
()home (línea 16)
()dojo.js (línea 237)
()dojo.js (línea 236)
(undefined="1000")dojo.js (línea 237)
[Detener en este error] b._contentSetter&&b._contentSetter.par...=u.getLocalization("dijit","loading",
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing some strange things. What I suppose is that you want a `TextBox` **inside** a `ContentPane`, if i'm not right, then forget the following answer.

There are several mistakes in this code:

While creating your `appLayout` contentpane, you're providing the second argument (which you use to put `"appLayout"` in. This argument is used to define the DOM node (or the ID of the DOM node) that should be used to place the contentpane at. You **don't** have a DOM node with an ID called `appLayout`. For more information look at the [API documention](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/dijit/layout/ContentPane) which says that the second parameter is the `srcNodeRef`. The solution is to leave this parameter empty.

Then the second mistake is that you're placing the `TextBox` inside the `ContentPane` even before it was placed on the DOM itself and started up. So re-arranging your code so the `ContentPane` is placed on the grid container first will work.

The complete code, with changes:

```
dojo.require('dojo.store.JsonRest');
dojo.require('dijit.layout.ContentPane');
dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
dojo.require('dojox.grid.DataGrid');
dojo.require('dojo.data.ObjectStore');
dojo.require('dijit.form.TextBox');
dojo.require('dojox.data.AndOrReadStore');
dojo.require('dojo._base.xhr');
dojo.require('dojo.json')
dojo.require('dojo.domReady');

dojo.ready(function() {

    var appLayout = new dijit.layout.ContentPane({
        id: "appLayout"
    });
    appLayout.placeAt('gridContainer');
    appLayout.startup();

    var textBox = new dijit.form.TextBox({
        name: "searchbox",
        placeHolder: "Search ..."
    });
    textBox.placeAt('appLayout');              
});
```

Or as a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g00glen00b/Mtpp9/).
The startup is probably not required to be able to place the TextBox, but now the code is grouped a bit better.

I would also like to suggest to update your code to use the asynchronous syntax (Dojo 1.7+) since the syntax you're using is deprecated since 1.7 and since you're using 1.9 I don't see any benefit from writing new code with the old syntax since it will not work in Dojo 2.0.